# Carry previous parameters over to next django template request

Tags: python, django, django-templates, parameter-passing

I have a project that lists a number of items in a certain order.  This order is determined by two variables that are passed through parameters:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href={{ request.path }}?key={{ key }}&orientation={{ orientation }}><i class="icon-wrench icon-large"></i></a>
```

"key" is the item characteristic, and "orientation" is ascending or descending.  The python code handles the ordering of the items that are passed back to the template.

I have another control that needs to pass a time constraint:

```
<a href={{ request.path }}?time={{ time }}>{{ value }}</a>
```

Where time is the number of minutes.

The issue here is that if the user clicks the sort link and then clicks the time link, {{ request.path }} will only include the "proper path", not the additional parameters that had been added.

The first sort click would yield something like

```
/list/items/?key=importance&orientation=asc
```

But the second click would return

```
/list/items/?time=30
```

Where I instead wanted to return

```
/list/items/?key=importance&orientation=asc&time=30
```

Now I could use this instead

```
<a href={{ request.get_full_path }}?time={{ time }}>{{ value }}</a>
```

But if the time link is clicked multiple times, I could end up with something like this:

```
/list/items/?key=importance&orientation=asc&time=30&time=60&time=15
```

Multiple paremeters of the same type when really I would have wanted to overwrite the original parameter of this type.

How can I resolve this issue.  I'd like to retain all parameters that are not of the type being passed by the click link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2105/. Example:

```
{% load add_get_parameter %}
<a href="{% add_get_paramater param1='const_value',param2=variable_in_context %}">
    Link with modified params
</a>
```

Comment: Great!  I used the modified version here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2428/